# Compact way to write inference rule with bussproofs

Tags: pdftex, mathjax, bussproofs

I have the following inference rule

[image]

That I need to write with the package `bussproofs` and use it in the mathjax.

Mathjax support the [bussproofs](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/bussproofs.html)

I have no idea how to reproduce the following inference rule with the same form, like `<A, []> -> []`

To write these rules I used the `proof` but it is not available on mathjax

Comment: I highly doubt that it can be read by MathJaX which is not LaTeX. In my opinion, this is not possible with bussproofs but with other methods.

Comment: @Sebastiano there is the support for bussproofs https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/bussproofs.html but maybe I'm missing somethings

Comment: I didn't know that and I apologize, but have you tried anything? +1 for the question. Also post the link to the question maybe it's helpful for everyone. Greetings.

Comment: I'm working on it to have somethings workable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should set your proof in `bussproofs` and work in MathJax:

```
\newcommand\inf[2]{$\langle#1,[]\rangle\rightarrow #2$}

\begin{prooftree}
  \AXC{}\RL{num}
  \UIC{\inf{1}{1}}
  \AXC{}\RL{var}
  \UIC{\inf{x}{0}}\RL{gt}
  \BIC{\inf{x>1}{false}}
  \AXC{}\RL{skip}
  \UIC{\inf{skip()}{[]}}\RL{if}
  \BIC{\inf{if(x>1)then(x:=10)else(skip())}{[]}}
\end{prooftree}
```

Note, that the `\inf` macro sets your inference rules.